# Let an unelevated user kill all his processes successfully

Tags: shell, users, kill

## Situation

I have set up an environment where users can login from multiple endpoints and use `tmux`, `screen` ... so when they end their work they can either logout of their ssh session which doesn't kill any process kept in any terminal multiplexer, they can either do a `pkill -u ${USER}` or `killall -u ${USER}` to kill all their process, for that I wrap the function inside a script named `fulllogout`.

## Problem

When running `pkill -u ${USER}` or `killall -u ${USER}`, the killing process can kill itself or it's shell before killing all other processes which result in some process kept alive.

How can I do it successfully without allowing elevated rights ?

Comment: `pkill` doesn't kill itself. Your problem is probably that some processes are ignoring the `TERM` signal (eg. interactive shells), or are _stopped_, in which case the signal will only reach them if woken up. "Elevated rights" will not help with any of those. I suggest you do a `fulllogout()( pkill -HUP -u "$USER"; pkill -CONT -u "$USER"; pgrep -u "$USER" && { sleep 10; pkill -KILL -u "$USER"; } &)` instead (untested).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kill -TERM -1` will send SIGTERM to every process it had permission to do so (except pid 1), likewise `kill -KILL -1`  will kill everything possible. This is done in a single system call so can not kill itself part way through.